# Fitting nonstationary ARIMA-GARCH models

Tags: time-series, arima, garch, stationarity

What's the best strategy for nonstationary ARIMA-GARCH model fitting? 
For example, let $x_{t}$ to be an $I(1)$ series.

Theoretically, I could fit it for original series - $(1-L)x_{t}$ part doesn't affect on MA part in ARMA equation.

So, there are 2 strategies to fit in theoretical look:

1. Fit from original series ARMA(p+1, q)-GARCH(P, Q) model with 1 unit root in AR part.
2. Fit from differenced series ARMA(p, q)-GARCH(P, Q) model and expand this model to ARMA(p+1, q) by recalculating AR part polynomial, replacing $(1-L)x_{t}$ by $x_{t} - x_{t-1}$ and summing same coefficients.

But I think that it could be not so good to fit ARIMA-GARCH model for original series instead of differenced series in numeric. 
Is it correct? Should I use 2nd strategy for model checking and calibration?

I use rugarch package for my calculation in R.

Thank you.

P.S. Sorry, guys, I want to get an answer. So, could anyone help me a little? Maybe not an answer, but a link, where I could read about this.
Thank you.
So, maybe it's better to move this question to another group?

Comment: Damn. I strongly need an answer and I have not enough points here for making bounty for this question.((((

Comment: I suspect ARMA models with unit roots might be fit poorly and might have some undesirable features. I would difference the data and only then supply them to `rugarch`. Is there no mention of unit-root processes in the `rugarch` vignette?

Comment: @Richard Hardy, there is no direct way to choose I(N) model in rugarch. So, it's not a problem in theory - ARIMA(p, N, q) model has an equivalent representation as ARMA(p+N, q) model. But it's in theory representation...
So, what do you do, when your series is an I(N) process? Use strategy 2 from my post?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: @Richard Hardy Thnxs! So, other question - have you ever meet the situation, when you use clusterMap with try(ugarchspec(...)), try(ugarchfit(...)), but they don't work properly - code execution crashes on cluster nodes with same errors from ugarchfit? Probably, I should post in in stackoverflow? So, I've found same problem by this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r   but no realized bug fixing yet...

Comment: No, I have not tried using `rugarch` with parallell computing. Stack Overflow or an e-mail to Alexios Ghalanos (the author of the package) are better ways to clarify this.